# NodeJS / MySQL return results from a query to variable

Tags: mysql, node.js

I use NodeJS to insert data to a table with many to many relationship, and I want to include two foreign keys when I insert data into the table this is how my code looks:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE TransactionID > 1", function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      throw (err);
    } else if (res.length > 0) {
      console.log("Transaction already exit");
    } else {
      var transactionID;
      var filePK;
con.query("SELECT Filename FROM File WHERE Filename = ?", fileName, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      filePK = JSON.stringify(res);
});
con.query("SELECT TransactionDescriptionPK FROM TransactionDescription WHERE TransactionDescriptionPK > 0", function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      //console.log(res);
      transactionID = res;
});
var tran = {
    TransactionID: data.ID,
    TransactionDate: data.Description,
    Amount: data.Amount

};
con.query("INSERT INTO Transaction SET ?", tran, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

How I return the results from those queries so I can add them to the tran object?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you want to return the result of queries from your main function. This is not possible, you would have to use an async callback or promises, because the MySQL query is already asynchronus. For example, take a look at [this](https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/manage-async-nodejs-callback-example-code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    // you can directly pass the parallel callback to mysql query
    // if you don't need to do anything else
    return con.query(
      "SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE TransactionID > 1",
      callback
    );
  },
  function(callback) {
    // otherwise, just do you what you want (here JSON.stringify)
    // then don't forget to return the parallel callback
    return con.query(
      "SELECT Filename FROM File WHERE Filename = ?", 
      fileName,
      function(err, res) {
        if (err)
          return callback(err);
        const filePK = JSON.stringify(res);
        return callback(null, filePK);
      }
    );
  },
  function(callback) {
    return con.query(
      "SELECT TransactionDescriptionPK FROM TransactionDescription WHERE TransactionDescriptionPK > 0",
      callback
    );
  },
], function(err, data) {
  // if any mysql queries above encounter an error,
  // it calls the parallel final callback and stops other functions

  // without errors, data looks like :
  // data[0] equals mysql result object of the first query
  // data[1] equals filePK const
  // data[2] equals mysql result object of the last query

  const tran = {
    TransactionID: data[0][0].ID,
    TransactionDate: data[0][0].Description,
    // Amount: data.Amount // don't know where the amount come from,
                           // but you get the idea
  };
  con.query(
    "INSERT INTO Transaction SET ?",
    tran,
    function(err, res) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      // ...
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: it returns the same rows multiple times

Comment: I need more details to help... What is returning the same rows ?

Comment: results from this query    SELECT TransactionDescriptionPK FROM TransactionDescription WHERE TransactionDescriptionPK > 0           returns the same  rows multiple times

Comment: `console.log(data)` in the final callback to see what you get from functions above

Comment: and when i log data[2][0] resluts return this   this                     RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
RowDataPacket { TransactionDescriptionPK: 1 }
File already exit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111637/discussion-between-jerome-and-marcsimm).